# Problems installing windows 10 on Asus ROG G752VS OC edition with m.2 RAID0 boot

Tags: windows-10, drivers, pci-express, raid-0

I'm having trouble installing windows 10 on my Asus ROG G752VS OC edition laptop with two 512gb WD black PCIe NVMe drives installed and configured in raid0. I installed the drives and went into the bios and set the "SATA mode selection" to RAID. I then selected "Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology" in the bios and configured the raid volume then saved the settings and restarted the machine. Now when I go to install windows the raid volume does not show up all and all I can see is the secondary drive. I then downloaded the intel rapid storage technology driver and tried to load the driver when installing windows. The windows install will recognize the driver and try to install it and then blue screen and restart. I have tried the newest driver from intel as well as a few older versions from intel. I have also tried the driver from Asus. I have also tried installing windows from both usb and disk and have tried a windows 7 install with the same results. If I go into the bios and break the raid and set the drives back to ahci they will show up in the install as separate drives but I need them in raid0. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my raid working by configuring the raid in the bios like I had done before then installing windows on my secondary hard drive (not the raid drive). From inside windows I was able to install the Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver and software without crashing and could see the raid I created. I was then able to format the raid from windows disk management as a new hard drive. I then cloned my windows build from my secondary drive to my raid drive using easeUS todo backup software. Now the machine will boot from the raid with windows on it and I formatted my secondary drive to use for storage. This is by far not the best way to do this but was the only way I could get it to work. Hope this helps anyone else having the same issue.